# Django adding an extra unmanaged field to instance in post_save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to perform a HTTP request in my `post_save` and in case of a failure to connect to the service I want to send a message back to the user via the response from the `view`. My post_save looks something like this:

```
def test_post_save(instance, created, **dummy):
  if created:
    try:
      success = request_function(instance.item.id)
      if success:
        log.debug('Request succeeded')
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
      instance.stop = instance.start
      instance.save()
      log.debug('Request failed')
```

The above code works just fine, What I want to do is to add a field to the instance or in someway return a message back to the view's `create` function which utilizes `serializer.data` that the request failed.

I was hoping to achieve this without adding an extra column on the model's table. I've read about unmanaged models but I couldn't find any reference to an unmanaged field. Is there any other way for me to achieve this?

My end goal is to basically send back a message in the response to the client letting them know that the connection failed.

Comment: Have you considered having the client make the follow-up request rather than having the clients request have to last long enough for the server to make another? This design is prone to timeouts.

Comment: You say that "the above code works just fine" but it actually has two major flaws. The first one is that signals handlers are not async, so as @schillingt mentions this can easly make your own front timeout. The second, even worse, is that calling `instance.save()` from a post_save handler will start a potentally infinite recursion.  You definitly want to use an async task queues instead (celery, huey or other).

Comment: Edited my question to add in the `created` conditional I missed which should take care of the recursion in `instance.save()` I'm not too bothered by the timeout, its an internal server that's going to respond to this so it should be very fast.

Comment: You definitely should not add any columns to your model just so that DRF's serialization works automatically. You could probably add some state to the Python `instance` object (e.g. `instance._success = True`) and then read that state in the view. It's a bit ugly, since signal handlers were not designed to communicate back to the caller.

Comment: That's something I tried but adding a field like that will not be available to me in the view since the serializer will not serialize it. So when I do `serializer.data()` I'll only get the fields which are present on the model. Is there another way to get the instance back in the view?